# Error while creating a react app using create-react-app --> Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\Git\...'

Tags: reactjs, git-bash

Please see the output in git bash, below.

I installed the latest version of Node and npm.
I have run these three commands:

- npm uninstall -g create-react-app
- npx create-react-app myfirstreactapp
- node --trace-warnings ...

The error states that a module cannot be found but I am not sure what module is being referred to?

I hope someone can help.

```
> npm uninstall -g create-react-app

up to date, audited 1 package in 1s

found 0 vulnerabilities
> npx create-react-app myfirstreactapp
npm WARN exec The following package was not found and will be installed: create-react-app
(node:16020) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Program Files\Git\myfirstreactapp'
    at Object.mkdirSync (fs.js:987:3)
    at Object.module.exports.makeDirSync (C:\Users\alexl\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\mkdirs\make-dir.js:101:15)
    at createApp (C:\Users\alexl\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:255:6)
    at C:\Users\alexl\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:226:9
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:16020) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:16020) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

> node --trace-warnings ...
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\Git\...'
←[90m    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880
:15)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_ma
in.js:72:12)←[39m
←[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47←[39m {
  code: ←[32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'←[39m,
  requireStack: []
}
```

Comment: You don't have permissions to write files there.Don't use "Program Files" for your projects. Move them to some non system folder instead, like your user folder, or create new in root of `C:`, like `C:\Projects`

Comment: And if you still wants to use Program Files to create your projects, run the terminal as administrator.